# Cannot use bytes.Buffer as type io.WriterAt in func argument

Tags: go

Struggling with go today.. second question I've had to ask.

I've got 2 tests that test a write function `Write()`, that takes `writer io.WriterAt` and `content interface{}`.

I'm working with (2) tests written for the function, `TestWriteSuccessful` and `TestWriteFail`.

The error I'm getting for both functions when testing is:

```
cannot use &b (type *bytes.Buffer) as type io.WriterAt in argument to Write:
```

#### Question

What *does* implement WriterAt that I can replace bytes.Buffer with in these tests to make the tests functional?

#### What I've tried

1. Changing `b`'s type to `os.File` - the `b.len() > 0` fails then.
2. Extensively googled how to test io.WriterAt and functions implementing it, only thing I found was that bytes.Buffer *does NOT* implement an io.WriterAt, only io.Writer, but no further information.
3. Checked the godocs, I see that io.WriterAt calls `WriteAt` and takes a slice of bytes and an offset: `WriteAt(p []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)`, and I see that bytes.Buffer can be used to call `Write`, but no information about `WriteAt`

#### Code

Write function:

```golang
func Write(writer io.WriterAt, content interface{}) error {
    data, err := json.Marshal(content)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    writer.WriteAt(data, 0)
    return nil
}
```

Tests for Write function (test imports Testify):

```
func TestWriteSuccessful(t *testing.T) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    err := Write(&b, exampleSystemConfig)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.True(t, b.Len() > 0)
}

func TestWriteFail(t *testing.T) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    err := Write(&b, make(chan int)) // Write will return UnsupportedTypeError
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
}
```

#### Expected result

Both tests succeed.

#### Actual result

```
internal/platform/store/store_test.go:33:15: cannot use &b (type *bytes.Buffer) as type io.WriterAt in argument to Write:
        *bytes.Buffer does not implement io.WriterAt (missing WriteAt method)
internal/platform/store/store_test.go:40:15: cannot use &b (type *bytes.Buffer) as type io.WriterAt in argument to Write:
        *bytes.Buffer does not implement io.WriterAt (missing WriteAt method)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. `bytes.Buffer` isn't a `WriterAt`, and you seem to know that, so... ?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm trying to figure out _what I can_ pass to type WriterAt to make the tests functional. If bytes.Buffer doesn't work, are there any alternatives? Besides not using WriterAt :)

Comment: Given that the function writes at hard coded offset 0, is io.WriterAt needed?  When using *os.File, call [File.Stat](https://godoc.org/os#File.Stat) to get the size of the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to make your own `WriterAt` for testing purposes — it's any type that implements a `WriteAt` function with the correct signature. If you're only interested in knowing the number of bytes written, it can be as simple as

```
type TestWriter struct {
    BytesWritten int
}

func (tw *TestWriter) WriteAt(b []byte, _ int64) (n int, err error) {
    tw.BytesWritten += len(b)
    return len(b), nil
}
```

then you can test with

```
func TestWriteSuccessful(t *testing.T) {
    var tw TestWriter
    err := Write(&tw, exampleSystemConfig)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.True(t, tw.BytesWritten > 0)
}

func TestWriteFail(t *testing.T) {
    var tw bytes.Buffer
    err := Write(&tw, make(chan int)) // Write will return UnsupportedTypeError
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
}
```

Comment: Seems to work.. Only error I'm getting back now is 
```internal/platform/store/store_test.go:41:9: undefined: WriteAt
internal/platform/store/store_test.go:48:9: undefined: WriteAt
```

Comment: figured it out. Thank you so much. Tests passed with 100% coverage. So what exactly makes this work? I understand you create a struct with `BytesWritten int`, and then you created a function `WriteAt` that returns a length of bytes written. Is this essentially monkeypatching the WriterAt interface in the test?

Comment: You're not monkeypatching anything. You're creating a type that does the interface, and you're passing it to a function that requires a type that does the interface.

Comment: `s/does/implements/g`, at least as far as Golang parlance goes.  A type is said to "implement" an interface if it has all of the methods defined in it.  And yes, as @hobbs pointed out, interfaces are fulfilled implicitly, simply by having the methods.  If a function takes an interface argument, you can craft a type that implements that interface and it simply works.  No monkeypatching or hackery involved.